# copy redis keys from one ec2 to another ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, copy, migrate

There are 100k keys in my ec2. I want to copy all keys to another ec2 without BGSAVE and SAVE commands. I want to copy all keys with Linux command. Is there any Linux command to do so?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like 'lakh' in here.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can moves your Redis keys from one instance to another by below command

Option One

```
MIGRATE HOSTNAME PORT "" 0 5000 KEYS key1 key2 key3
```

Option Second

```
COPY HOSTNAME PORT "" 0 5000 KEYS key1 key2 key3
```

Hoping this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [MIGRATE command](https://redis.io/commands/migrate)?